# What is this noise?

Tags: noise, dialogue

Hey all,

I'm currently working on a project where some of the dial contains this noise and it's driving me nuts.

I've expanded, de-noised and EQ'd, but I can't get rid of it without the quality of the dial suffering.

Here's a sample: [click here](http://www.fred-pearson.com/Files/Noise.wav)

Does anyone know what it might be, or any suggestions on how to remove it? I'd be really grateful for any help!

Cheers,

Fred

Answer (score 1):

RX2 is your best bet. Treat the crackle and the noise separately. Decrackle the crackles first (you can use decrackle locally to the offending areas) and you're left with noise.

I don't know what it is, but something (well, that something is that there's some sort of signal modulation going on) tells me it has to do with electronic interference (i.e. another electronic gadget or a signal is being picked up somewhere in the signal chain).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try and treat them seperately!

Answer (score 0):

Agh, what a nightmare of a noise. There's definitely something weird going on there. Is it on everything?

I'm afraid, in my experience, something like that is impossible to totally eliminate. You can denoise and use a multiband expander (like Waves C4 or W43) to start with. It sounds like your dialogue is pretty well miked, so that helps you.

Beyond that, i wouldn't try too much with eq, as you'll cut into the dialogue. You could get into your volume automation and ride it as hard as you can. You then *maybe* cover the rest with a pretty broadband atmos track.

I'd seriously consider ADR, if it's an option. This interference is insidious in that it's broadband, contains a lot of energy in higher frequencies vital to dialogue, AND is made up of a whole heap of tiny transients.

Best of luck with it!

Comment: Luckily, it's only a short segment of the project, and it's only on some of the takes of the rushes. However, it's pretty noticeable when the clean dial cuts to this. 

I agree that the solution is probably to treat it as much as possible, then try and mask what's left with a broadband atmos track. I hadn't tried a multi-band expander either, so that's my next stop. ADR isn't an option (typical haha!).

Oh well, looking forward to the challenge! Thanks for your help Roger.

Comment: @Fred No worries man! Another option is to see if you can use any lines from unaffected alternate takes/slates as replacements. You'd need the performances to be very similar, and the sync to be close enough to cut, but it could be worth a shot. 

Answer (score 0):

Of it is periodic, you can try to eliminate it with phase cancelation.

Answer (score 0):

This is RF noise from a poorly tuned radio microphone. You will not be able to remove this adequately for the dialogue to be used and it will need to be ADR'd.